# Android Button animation will start when GPS location acquired

Tags: android, animation, gps

I have an application, which calculate distance after every 100 meters. There is a button and a text view. The button that I used, is an animated button. When I click Button, button spin(Animation Start v.startAnimation(animRotate)). But I need the button animation when acquire the location from GPS.

Here is my activity:

```
public class Gps extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
startStop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        R.anim.anim_rotate);

start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!doubleclick) {
            v.startAnimation(animRotate);
            startStop.setText("Stop");
            lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);
            Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (loc == null) {
                display.setText("No GPS location found");
            } else {
                // set Current latitude and longitude
                currentLon = loc.getLongitude();
                currentLat = loc.getLatitude();

            }
            // Set the last latitude and longitude
            lastLat = currentLat;
            lastLon = currentLon;
            doubleclick = true;
        } else {
            lm.removeUpdates(Loclist);
            startStop.setText("Start");
            v.clearAnimation();
            doubleclick = false;
            Intent in = new Intent(Gps.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }

    }
});
}

LocationListener Loclist = new LocationListener() {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // start location manager
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Get last location
    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // Request new location
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);

    // Get new location
    Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // get the current lat and long
    currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
    currentLon = loc.getLongitude();

    Location locationA = new Location("point A");
    locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
    locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);

    Location locationB = new Location("point B");
    locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
    locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);
    if(lastLat != 0 || lastLon != 0){
    double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

    double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;

    display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
    }

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

};
```

Comment: v.startAnimation(animRotate); put this line into OnLocationChanged callback.

Comment: did you try doing this v.startAnimation(animRotate); in onLocationChanged??

Comment: @Techfist,how can I call the animation into OnLocationChanged callback? When I click button then it is v.startAnimation(animRotate);

Comment: Just write start.startAnimation(animRotate) in onLocationChanged, and check.